# warpPerspective and warpAffine is not working for large images, height>32k

Tags: opencv

I am trying to warp 16-bit satellite images. I have Panchromatic images. My reference image is 8192x81920 pixels, and a Red channel image is 4096x40960 pixels. When I use `warpAffine` or `warpPerspective`, pixels with row values greater than 32767 are not warped correctly. Is this a simple bug? May I correct it with change of variable types?

I have checked `warpPerspectiveInvoker` function but could not see an easy fix.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Be specific. How much memory in your pc?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to warp your image? And possibly a link to an example output? (I can edit it into your question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently I divided image into 32k sized tiles, and warped each indiviual tiles.
At the moment for my data results seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

This does appear to be an [open bug](http://www.code.opencv.org/issues/1337#note-2) in OpenCV. `cv::warpPerspective()` uses `short` internally to generate the distortion maps. 32767 is the maximum representable value in a `short`, so any values larger than this will cause problems.

You could try hacking the `warpPerspectiveInvoker` and replace `short` instances with something larger, like `int`, but I cannot guarantee this would work. It might be worth a try, though.